# mySQL won't start, I think my server was interrupted

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Complete novice here - I have a website on my local server I am trying to access made through wordpress and haven't had a problem with it up until now. I think my server was reset and then mySQL stopped connecting.

I followed the following advice that I found on here after a few command prompts that didn't work,

"I have recently encountered this problem on Mac OS Sierra too. Apache server is working but mysql is not. After searching for a solution, reading lots of posts I found this solution. And it worked!

The solution is to navigate to the mysql folder, in my case its,

/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/

and remove all the files except folders. Then restart MAMP again."

After this mySQL does activate and it brings me to the installation process again. Once I run through the installation process and click continue I get this..

> WordPress database error: [Table 'greenscapeprojects.wp_users' doesn't
> exist] CREATE TABLE wp_users ( ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL
> auto_increment, user_login varchar(60) NOT NULL default '', user_pass
> varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', user_nicename varchar(50) NOT NULL
> default '', user_email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', user_url
> varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', user_registered datetime NOT NULL
> default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', user_activation_key varchar(255) NOT
> NULL default '', user_status int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
> display_name varchar(250) NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (ID), KEY
> user_login_key (user_login), KEY user_nicename (user_nicename), KEY
> user_email (user_email) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE
> utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

Now the above error goes on and on for pages and at the very bottom I get, Success!

Wordpress has been installed

Username

Password

"Log in"

Once I click log in this is my next error

Not Found

The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server.

I have since deleted the new files and replaced them back with the original from my mySQL folder and i'm back to the start, with it not connecting.

Once I try /phpmyadmin on my local host I get this.

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
Retry to connect

Can anyone help and if possible in a way someone who doesn't understand code can read?

Thank you very much for your time,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a linux background so I might be slightly off..

The mysql56 directory would have contained the socket file used to connect to mysql, giving the 2002 error you have at the bottom.

I think in your case, if you can uninstall and re-install from scratch you will end up in a much cleaner position.  I think deleting all the files in the mysql56 directory was a bad suggestion, there are table mapping files there I think...

The alternative is to [Recreate the mysql socket file](https://serverfault.com/questions/617098/how-to-get-mysql-sock-file-mistakenly-deleted-from-mysql-tmp), but as a Novice I think your best bet is to do a clean new installation to keep things simple.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jango, 

If I uninstall and re-install from scratch (are you talking about uninstalling MAMP?) will my website and files still be retained or will they be wiped? Should I back them up before hand? I got this far with my website watching youtube video's so i'm not even aware of where my website files are actually kept (e.g. are they in the MAMP folder I will be uninstalling).

Thanks for the reply,

Comment: Sorry i've not used MAMP before, my suggestions are all from a linux background.  Definitely backup whenever you can though (:  Sorry can't be more help.  But if the setup is like linux, there were important files in the mysql56 directory which don't auto-regenerate easily.

Comment: I tend to agree. I'm not sure what path MAMP uses for the MySQL socket file, but by deleting files from the MySQL data directory you probably caused other issues with your MySQL databases that can be difficult to recover from. I am pretty sure that stopping and starting the MySQL server/daemon will recreate the socket file, but can't help you with the other problems that now exist with your datadir.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys... I had a locally build website - where a bouts in my computer/MAMP folder would this be stored so that I can backup and drop back in once reinstalled? Or do you think I have potentially lost all my content? 

If so, I can rebuild (shitty, i'm so damn slow haha). Where can I learn about basic coding to stop this kind of stuff happening in the future and what files do I need to back up incase of this happening again. 
I initially learnt about WordPress off lynda.com. 

Thank you both for your help and time, appreciate it!